# Paper folded effect not working in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, css

I was working on folded paper effect and this seems to work on almost all browsers except IE8.

Here is the JSBIN code : http://jsbin.com/oLepimiK/6/edit

[image]

I saw a different question on SOF where :before and :after tags are supported, but I guess I am missing something here. Can someone point that out to me?

MY IE8 MODE:

[image]

Comment: You need for it to be css based correct?

Comment: Added one solution, at least it helps you debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working, you are having problems with `Z-INDEX`, and I changed the top and left to `-1`.

```
.clear{
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.complaint:after {
  border-color: transparent #F58C1E #F58C1E   transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 12;
}

.complaint:before {
  border-color: white #A65807 #A65807 white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 11px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  content: "";
  left: -1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 11;
}

.complaint {
  background-color: #F58C1E;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0;
  padding: 4px;
  position: relative;
}
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

Comment: in your screenshot how are you getting the options in the right ?

Comment: I am positive, I will double check.

Comment: ok.. thanks, can you provide the link for the final version ?

Comment: i added `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` to the top of the document and it works just fine. Thanks for helping me out !

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `box-shadow` is not supported in IE8, so the shadow under the 'fold' will not appear.

[**CanIUse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow)